# Wolfram Cloud Question - VectorPlot3D

Tags: plotting, wolfram-cloud

I tried Mathematica in the Wolfram Cloud when it first came out.  I found it riddled with glitches.  I'm attempting to give a second shot now.  I tried plotting the following code:

```
VectorPlot3D[{x,y,z},{x,-3,3},{y,-3,3},{z,-3,3}]
```

It returns a pink cell where if I hover over it says "Type Error: Null is not an object..."  Do you get the same error?  I've tried two different browsers with the same result.

So far I'm not too happy with Mathematica in the cloud.  I'm looking for a solution present my mathematica files in the classroom with an iPad.  I really wish Wolfram would make a native CDF player for the iPad.  They had a working version in 2012.  But I was told a few years ago that they put it on hold to work on the cloud.  Bummed about this as you can do a lot more with a native player.  Does anyone know if Wolfram is planning to make a native player in the near future?

I have an iPad pro with plenty of processing power.  I hope they will move in this direction soon.

Comment: It is working for me, although it did show what seemed to be a pink box as soon as I evaluated the cell. Within a second or so the 3D vector plot got displayed in place of the pink box. I wanted to show the screenshot for this, but it would then have to be an answer and not a comment. FWIW I am on Windows 10 with Firefox.

Comment: Strange.  I've tried multiple times.  It worked once as you described.  But haven't been able to get it to work since even after resetting my browser.

Comment: Have you tried the [Wolfram Cloud app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wolfram-cloud/id978701305)?

Comment: FYI... It looks like we will be getting a CDF player on iOS soon.  Got this email message today... "I emailed the project manager who is leading that project and they actually have a tentative release within the next few months."

Answer (score 1):

I use *Mathematica Online* on Google Chrome. I put in your code and it loaded without any pink boxes or anything. This is what I got:

[image: <code>VectorPlot3D</code>]

I have an iPad mini, and I did a search on the App Store. Here's what I found:

- WolframAlpha Viewer, by Wolfram Group LLC, for free
- Wolfram Cloud, by Wolfram Group LLC, for free. This is the one you want. This one allows you to view your files in your account, adjust sliders, shows documentation, AND allows you to edit your files.

Interestingly enough, the Wolfram Cloud app is also available on Google Play - perfect if you have a Chromebook.